# MongoDB query insert field into document from a list of Id's

Tags: mongodb, insert

I'm kind of stuck with the following problem. I have a MongoDB filled with documents, of these documents (I have a list with Id's) I need to insert a field.

I have this document:

```
 {
   "id" : 3639,
   "type" : "P",
   "createdate" : "2011-10-19T11:45:14+0200",
   "name_creator" : "",
   "latitude" : "50.887",
   "longitude" : "9.14999",
   "themes" : [{
       "name" : "Fun",
       "id" : "4"
        }, {
       "name" : "Kids",
       "id" : "5"
   }]
}
```

I need a query the can insert the themes field into the document, the current themes field does not have to be updates, just 1 new one. I have over 300 Id's where this has to be done.

The document should then look like this:
(all the other fields in themes should be removed, just one new one 'Outside')

```
 {
   "id" : 3639,
   "type" : "P",
   "createdate" : "2011-10-19T11:45:14+0200",
   "name_creator" : "",
   "latitude" : "50.887",
   "longitude" : "9.14999",
   "themes" : [{
       "name" : "Outside",
       "id" : "6"
        }]
}
```

I would normally write a bit of Java code that would loop over the documents and change them, but I believe (hope) this could be done in a query.

Anyone got an idea on how I could do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
db.collection.update(
  {id : {$in : [your list of ids]}},
  {$set : {
    theme : [{
       "name" : "Outside",
       "id" : "6"
    }]
  }},
  {multi : true}
)
```

Comment: Wow that looks simple!! I'm not able to try right now, but I suppose the list of id's would be a comma seperated list?

Comment: You're a hero, thanks very much it works! Everyday learning new things with MongoDB and people like you and others on this website, helping me with it. Fantastic!!

Comment: glad that you appreciate this. Also it is a nice opportunity to learn for me as well. I answer questions, see answers of other people and see is there a way to do it better then my approach.

Comment: Hi, it seems to only change the last id in the $in list.

Comment: Found it, needed to add: multi:true

db.collection.update({id : {$in : [your list of ids]}},{$set : {theme : [{"name" : "Outside","id" : "6"}]}}, {multi:true})